# Styling checkbox as square

Tags: javascript, css, checkbox

I am trying to customize my check box .
In  the jsfiddle where you can see the customized check box which is circle . I just want to make it a square and I need help to do it . 
Can someone help me. The fiddle link is     http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/125/

```
border-radius : 100%
```

Makes it a circle, how to make it as a square ??

Comment: Delete `border-radius` property from `.checkboxFour label`.

Comment: It didn't work for me .. But setting it 0 worked ..

Comment: How did I fail to try that.. Played with all the numbers except 0 :(

Comment: I did upvote .. :)

Comment: Hi, something like this https://lokesh-coder.github.io/pretty-checkbox/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the `border-radius: 100px;` property from the `.checkboxFour label` **or** set it to 0.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/126/)

Comment: i need your help.. i couldnt able to align the label next to checkbox. i tried adding seperate label with vertical-alignment : middle but nothing worked :(

Comment: @ani Make a new question, post your whole code and give me the link! (:

Comment: question is posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42650324/customized-check-box-and-label-alignment

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the border radius directives or set

```
 border-radius : 0;
```